# How to implement reauthentication in firebase auth?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, security, firebase-authentication

**delete account**

```
  const handleDelete = async function () {
    const auth = getAuth();
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    const promises = [];
    const userCollections = [
      `${user.email}_data`,
      `${user.email}_data/bookmarked_movies/bookmarks`,
      `${user.email}_data/bookmarked_movies/bookmarks_trace`,
    ];
    const userDocs = [`${user.email}_data/collection_list`];
    userCollections.map(async (colRef) => {
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, colRef));
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.data());
        promises.push(deleteDoc(doc.ref));
      });
    });
    await Promise.all(promises);

    const credential = promptForCredentials();

    reauthenticateWithCredential(user, credential)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("user is reauthenticated");
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));

    deleteUser(user).catch((err) => console.log(err));

    navigate("../../");
  };
```

I'm implementing delete user account functionality, and I'm stuck on deleting the user from auth. Ok, so to delete the user you have to actually sign in recently or you have to reauthenticate if you signed in too much time before, for security reasons they say. The problem is I don't really understand how to implement that? How that works? I understand that `proptForCredentials()` function should return some data and assign it to the `credential` variable, but I don't understand how to implement that. Can someone explain that to me?

Comment: Which auth method are you using? Email password, Google... ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Email password